# Please clarify my question on why the audience may have been laughing at a speaker

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions, asking-questions

The question is [Laughing at Dr Alexander Murry's presentation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199340). I initially got an upvote, but this was followed by 1 downvote and 4 close votes for "Unclear what you're asking". I have edited between the 3rd and 4th close votes. Please help me improve further, if need be.

Comment: FWIW I don't think your question is unclear as it it essentially "Why was Dr Murry laughed at, if he was?" However, some people may have closed because either 1) it's so long they didn't bother reading or 2) the list of options is a bit confusing. Though they are just guesses and are not necessarily correct.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I hope people are not actually closing questions without reading them.

Comment: @Alex Me to but it can happen.

Comment: FWIW this got left closed in the reopen queue.

Comment: And has been reopened outside of the queue.

Comment: It's pretty long and a lot of it is largely unnecessary.

Comment: @Valorum: "Too long" is not a valid close reason.  It is an *especially* poor reason to VTC as "unclear what you're asking" given that the resulting message encourages making the question longer.  (Yes, too much detail *can* make something unclear.  No, that does not mean we get to entirely ignore the resulting UX.)

Comment: @Kevin - OP was also looking for advice on how to improve the question *generally*. Taking an axe to it would be an excellent start imho

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question does not appear to be unclear per my reading of it. The question appears to boil down to "Why are the audience laughing and what/who are they laughing at?" This is a perfectly clear question. I have made some slight formatting changes but that is only to get content inline with the numbered list. It would be better, however, to have a title for your question that better describes what you are asking rather than something a bit generic.

To address why people *may* have voted to close, though I of course don't speak for them.

1. It's so long they didn't read it - a TL;DR section can help for this but you've added the "questions" section now which should be better.
2. The list of potential options is a bit confusing; I agree with it is quite confusing and long but it does give some nice leads and shows you've thought about it yourself so I'd say keep it. - This has been cleared up a bit by bolding the heading.

Overall though this post seems clear and has been improved so it should be reopened.